# Struts servlet reusing HttpServlet object so parms get overwritten

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts

OK, this is baffling to me. I have a servlet that returns data for some graphical charts on a dashboard. The servlet takes an 'action' parm which tells it which DB query to run. This servlet is called 2 times on the dashboard page to return 2 different sets of data. My servlet looks like this :

```
public class SrvData extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String action;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        action = request.getParameter("action");
        if ( action.equals("getStatus") ) {
           // run some query
        }
        else if ( action.equals("getUsers") ) {
           // run some query
        }
        response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(data));
    }
```

}

And it is called 2 separate places from my dashboard jsp like this :

```
$.get("/SrvData", { 'action' : 'getStatus' })
    .done(function (dbData) {
        // process the data and build chart
    });
$.get("/SrvData", { 'action' : 'getUsers' })
    .done(function (dbData) {
        // process the data and build chart
    });
```

with the action being different for each type of chart. In the Chrome debugger, I see the correct called being made in the Network tab :

```
SrvData?action=getStatus    GET 200 application/json    jquery-1.11.2.js:9659   277 B   15.47 s 
SrvData?action=getUsers     GET 200 application/json    jquery-1.11.2.js:9659   277 B   18.96 s
```

Now heres the problem. SOMETIMES (and I cant figure what triggers it) while the msgs posted to the servlet are correct, when the servlet code above is called, the action ALWAYS EQUALS 'getUsers' - for every call! In eclipse debugger, I see that the actual SrvData object is the SAME EXACT object! When I slow it down in the UI and Eclipse debuggers I can actually SEE the parm being changed in the paused first call servlet after the second GET request is sent.

This is just crazy! How can struts/tomcat use the SAME EXACT servlet object for more than one request? Why doesn't it instantiate a new object for every request? Is there some setting I have to change to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can struts/tomcat use the SAME EXACT servlet object for more than one request?

Not only it can, but it **must** reuse the exact same object. That's what is specified in the servlet specifications. A servlet is a singleton.

Just stop using fields when you should use local variables, in order to make your code thread-safe:

```
public class SrvData extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if ( action.equals("getStatus") ) {
           // run some query
        }
        else if ( action.equals("getUsers") ) {
           // run some query
        }
        response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(data));
    }
}
```

Note that this has absolutely nothing to do with Struts: you're using a plain old servlet, which is unrelated to Struts.

Comment: Wow, I would not expect that. Is there a reason it 'MUST'? This seems ripe for problems such as I've described. I guess its impossible to have class object attributes in a servlet, even if they aren't static The reason I used them is because my 5 different servlets all have parms 'action' 'blah1' and 'blah2'. So I consolidated them into a 'BaseServlet' object class, which my 5 serlvets extend. This base servlet does the 'getParamater()' calls so I dont have the same code copied into 5 different servlets.

Comment: I hate having duplicate code cause if I need to add a 4th 'common' parm, now I have to add it in 5 places, which is stupid and opens the door to errors. Why were servlets designed this way?

Comment: @user3708842 You would have to ask the designers why. Servlets have a life-cycle: they are initialized, then used many times, and finally destroyed. If they were not singletons, the potentially costly initialization would have to be executed at each request. Your base servlet shouldn't have fields. It should have methods that can be called from the subclasses.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't agree with their design choice but I guess I have to live with it...